# Display append function in another new activity

Tags: javascript, android

I am doing an application which contains a listview of phone contact with a checkbox. I have found a coding that suits to my project. It works well but it does not operate as i want. I dont want 'respondText' appear in toast function, i just want it displayed in another new activity after the button clicked. I have tried the intent function, i put it under the toast funstion but the application does not perform. Maybe i just misplaced the function, what is the actual solution to handle this problem? Here is it :

```js
private void checkButtonClick() {

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showAppend);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
            responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

            ArrayList<Contacts> countryList = dataAdapter.contactList;
            for (int i = 0; i < countryList.size(); i++) {
                Contacts country = countryList.get(i);
                if (country.isSelected()) {
                    responseText.append("\n" + country.getName());
                }
            }

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseText,
                    //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            
            Intent startNewAct = new Intent(ListViewCheckboxesActivity.thisthis, DisplayAppendActivity.class);
            startActivity(startNewAct);
            
            textView.setText(responseText);
            
        }
    });

}
```

Here is another new activity:

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DisplayAppendActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displayappend);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showAppend);

        String responseText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("responseText");


        textView.setText(responseText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data through Intent. When starting actvity from intent you can use:

```
Intent startNewAct = new Intent(ListViewCheckboxesActivity.this, DisplayAppendActivity.class);
startNewAct.putExtra("responseText", responseText);
startActivity(startNewAct);
```

And you can get this responseText in another activity onCreate:

```
String responseText = getIntent().getExtras().getString("responseText");
```

Comment: I have put the code in both activities.. but it shows error in the line "startNewAct.putExtra("responseText", responseText);". It suggest me to choose between two 'Cast 2nd parameter to 'java.io.Serializable' or 'Cast 2nd parameter to 'java.lang.CharSequence'. While in the onCreate activity, it shows that variable responseText is never used.. what should I do afterward? Do I need to add library in both activities?

Comment: On this line:
    startNewAct.putExtra("responseText", responseText);
the responseText must be String. So try something this:
     startNewAct.putExtra("responseText", responseText.toString());

Comment: Tq.. OK.. that way fix my error... but it still do not perform well after I launched the app.. Do I need to make something else on my onCreate activity? I want it displays in textview.. i have declared textview with id assigned.. I put "textView.setText(responseText);" under the String responseText line.. Am i doing the right way? Or there is another way?

Comment: @AjMal: You should search for sending data between Activities. It will fix your error. This answer should be accepted answer

Comment: @MrNeo tq.. I've done that,,, but can i  display it in textview? Or there is another way to display it? Do I need to make changes in AndroidManifext.xml?

Comment: You will use it as a `String`. And in `AndroidManifest.xml`, you need to declare `secondActivity`. Kindly check [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)